# Using beeline to execute multiple hql files that take same hive variables

Tags: hive, parameters, hql, beeline

Is it possible to send hive variables to multiple hql files and execute them in a single hive session?

would this work

$beeline -u "{$url}" --hivevar FROM=2020 --hivevar TO=2021 -e "$(cat loadTable1.hql loadTable2.hql)"

Where both the hqls take these two variables as parameters.
-Thanks

Comment: This is working for the first query, the second query doesn't pick up the variables and returns no wows after execution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested it, does it work? In theory I think it should.

If not, maybe you can create a temp hql file before beeline and use it instead?

```
cat loadTable1.hql loadTable2.hql > temp_load.hql

$beeline -u "{$url}" --hivevar FROM=2020 --hivevar TO=2021 -f temp_load.hql
```

Comment: In my tests, the variables are being picked up by the first hql and not the second one. I shall try it your way and see, thanks for the response.